# How to fetch matched data from first table and unmatched from second table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with same structure 
eg. Table A and B with columns id,value.

```
Table A

ID    VALUE
1      10
2      20
3      0


Table B

ID    VALUE
1      24
2      26
3      0
4      40
5      50

    expected output:

ID    VALUE
1      10
2      20
3      0
4      40
5      50
```

as per output first three id is matched with table B so id(1,2,3) with value comes from table A and id(4,5) with value is not matched so it comes from table B.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `right join` on table b (or a `left join` on table a) and use a `coalesce` operator.

```
select b.id, coalesce(a.value, b.value)
from tablea a
right join tableb b on a.id = b.id
```

or

```
select b.id, coalesce(a.value, b.value)
from tableb b
left join tablea a on a.id = b.id
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15f01a/5)